# Function with no arguments but with type in Julia

Tags: function, methods, types, julia

I recently go through some source codes of Julia and find some functions seem mysterious to me.

There is some function defined in Julia source code where they have no arguments but do have type annotations.

For example: line 20 in [abstractarray.jl](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/blob/0c24dca65c031820b91721139f0291068086955c/base/abstractarray.jl#L20)

I try the `ndims` function a bit,

it seems like `ndims` can take the type itself as argument and return the correct value:

```
julia> ndims(AbstractArray{Float64, 2})
       2
julia> ndims([1.1 0.3; 0. 0.5])
       2
```

Can someone explain to me how `(::DataType)` works in methods?
Or what does it mean in Julia?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

When exploring the behavior of a function in Julia, it is important to understand *which* specific *method* is being called. Julia is organized around [multiple dispatch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), so a single name such as `ndims` may be associated with different implementations -- chosen by the type of the arguments. To see how `ndims` is implemented, we can use the `@which` macro to determine the implementation chosen for a specific invocation:

```
julia> @which ndims(AbstractArray{Float64, 2})
ndims{T,n}(::Type{AbstractArray{T,n}}) at abstractarray.jl:61

julia> @which ndims([1.1 0.3; 0. 0.5])
ndims{T,n}(::AbstractArray{T,n}) at abstractarray.jl:60
```

The current implementations in `abstractarray.jl` are as follows:

```
ndims{T,n}(::AbstractArray{T,n}) = n
ndims{T,n}(::Type{AbstractArray{T,n}}) = n
```

Both signatures are [parametric methods](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/methods/#parametric-methods) taking the parameters `{T,n}`.

- The first signature is for an *instance* with the type `AbstractArray{T,n}` -- such as, in your example, `[1.1 0.3; 0. 0.5]` (below several layers of abstraction).
- The second signature is for the *type* `AbstractArray{T,n}` itself.

(neither signature names the argument, although they obviously both do accept an argument. because the behavior depends only on the type signature of the argument, a name is not required)

The underlying ideas are explained in the [types](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/types/) and [methods](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.3/manual/methods/) sections of the Julia manual.

Comment: Huh... I forget to use `@which` to make sure which method has been called.
In fact, to simplify my question, I just want to know what is the difference if I define `ndims` for the instances of `Array` as `ndims(arr::AbstractArray{T, n}) = n` rather than `ndims(::AbstractArray{T, n}) = n` which is found in the source code.

Comment: There is no difference -- second version still accepts an argument, it is simply unnamed. This works because the function is wholly dependent on the parameterization. The `{T,n}` are also "arguments", in some sense, but at the level of the type system. If you need to actually do something with `arr` then of course the argument must be named as in your first version.